# Specifying GET parameters with file urls

Tags: php, url, get

I am trying to recreate something like this

https://prithviresorts.files.wordpress.com/2020/04/cropped-img_2319.jpg?w=1000

where you have get parameters in the url and process the image file accordingly

I can't seem to work out how I can add php scripts to operate with such file urls

Comment: What webserver software are you using? Apache, nginx?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware XAMPP

Comment: In that case you can use [a .htaccess for Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) to [rewrite the URL](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) so you can redirect multiple URLs to one PHP script.

Comment: Will give it a try an get back

Comment: Once you know the method, you can find a lot of help on the internet.